# How to deal with missing values in the array in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Some of the values that I'm requesting may or maynot be returning a value as the api takes someones profile and they have left out fields in registration etc.

If I request something which isn't there in my twig template I get the error

```
 throw new Twig_Error_Runtime(sprintf('Key "%s" in object (with ArrayAccess) of type   "%s"     does not exist', $arrayItem, get_class($object)), -1, $this->getTemplateName());
```

I could solve this by doing this code on each value but it's messy and not clever is there a way of not getting the error, like in other php frameworks, it will just leave a blank

```
  {% if profile.aboutMe %}

  {{ profile.aboutMe }}
```

controller

```
     return   $this->render('LoginLogBundle:Default:userprofile.html.twig',array('profile'=>$user)));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`default()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) filter to display some text when a object or a value is not defined:

```twig
{{ profile.aboutMe|default('No profile') }}
{# or #}
{{ profile.aboutMe|default('-') }}
{# or #}
{{ profile.aboutMe|default('') }}
{# etc. #}
```

Comment: that didn't work for me, I used {% if profile.aboutMe is defined %} {%endif%}

Comment: How does it work not? What is the error? It works for me, I use Symfony 2.4.1.

Comment: I get the same error as first mentioned.  I assume as you and documentation suggests I only need to put {{ profile.aboutMe|default('No profile') }} anyway will go with other way for now

Comment: Can you please try this? `{{ profile.method(aboutMe|default('foo'))|default('foo') }}`